# how to make people put a specific sentence into a text form to move to next page?

Tags: java, javascript, forms, submit

I want to make a quiz page with a picture and a text form.
people see the picture and put the accurate words into the form.
if they are right, they move to the next question page by pushing the submuit button.
but I will show them the warning pop up window if they don't give a right answer.

how can I do these simple(?) matters with javascript?

Comment: have you done anything?

Comment: Is it just for fun, or security / cheating prevention is important?

Comment: I'm not expert at this. Ive googled many site and apply some sample to solve my matters,, but I couldn't get what I want..

Comment: It will be just for fun. but I hope no one can never move to next page with wrong answer.